# dataview within mobile page not finding pageName reference to intended mobile page

Tags: xpages, dataview, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I have a single page application that has multiple Mobile Pages.  I have a view level mobile page that targets another mobile page as follows:

```
<xe:appPage id="viewPage" pageName="viewPage" preload="true"
        resetContent="true">
        <xe:djxmHeading id="viewPageHeading" back="Back"
            label="Search Results" moveTo="homePage">
        </xe:djxmHeading>
        <xe:dataView rows="7" id="dataView1" pageName="#documentPage"
            openDocAsReadonly="true">
            <xe:this.summaryColumn>
```

The other Mobile Page is "documentPage" however I get the following error when clicking an entry:

dojox.mobile.View#performTransition: destination view not found:null

If I change the pageName reference to just 'documentPage' like:

```
<xe:dataView rows="7" id="dataView1" pageName="documentPage"
            openDocAsReadonly="true">
```

I then get a 404 item not found error as if it is looking for an additional xpage within the application.

Any ideas to get a successful target to the intended mobile page?

Thanks,

Geoff

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (shortned) example from the "XPages Extension Library Demo":

```
<xe:singlePageApp id="singlePageApp1" selectedPageName="dataView">
    .
    .
    .
    <xe:appPage resetContent="false" id="dataView" pageName="dataView" preload="true">
        <xe:djxmHeading id="mHeader8" label="Data View" back="Home" moveTo="home"></xe:djxmHeading>
        <xe:dataView id="dataView2" var="viewEntry"
            binding="#{viewStateBean.dataIterator}" collapsibleRows="true"
            collapsibleDetail="true" pageName="#document" columnTitles="true"
            rows="10">
            <xe:this.data>
                <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="AllThreadsByDate"
                    expandLevel="2">
                </xp:dominoView>
            </xe:this.data>
            .
            .
            .
        </xe:dataView>
    </xe:appPage>

    <xe:appPage id="document" pageName="document" resetContent="true" preload="true">
        <xe:djxmHeading id="mHeader8" label="Document" back="Back" moveTo="dataView" />
        <xp:panel>
            <xp:this.data>
                <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="Contact" />
            </xp:this.data>
            .
            .
            .
        </xp:panel>
    </xe:appPage>
</xe:singlePageApp>
```

The URL changes from

```
XPagesExt853.nsf/mobileDemo.xsp#dataView
```

to

```
XPagesExt853.nsf/mobileDemo.xsp#document&databaseName=XPagesExt853.nsf&documentId=454167BB5B230578C1257AD30048E761&action=editDocument
```

Comment: the only found difference is that I made the id of the app page the same as the pageName.  I have documentPage in the dataview and this is the name of the app page (id and pageName).  The link created is: //server.host.org/dev/PI.nsf/land.xsp#documentPage?databaseName=server/host!!dev\PI.nsf&documentId=99DDFFAC65B3807085257AD3004AF914&action=openDocument

Comment: still getting dojox.mobile.View#performTransition: destination view not found:null.

Comment: I see you have a question mark as seperator after the page name in the created link. If I change my link to that format I get the same error, but I don't know why your link is created differently.

Comment: which version of the extlib do you use? is your dataView showing data from another database?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  I am using the latest version just before 12/20 when they added another version.  This is spawning from another problem I was having.  If I create the xpage as "m_.." I get the custom css files inside the extlib that renders on the phones and the view to document dataview link works as expected.  However I have requirement to add a typeahead edit box on the initial page and the problem is that the android css does not render the field on the page correctly.

Comment: So I created a single page app without "m_" in the xpage title which fixes the field problem and I added tundra.css, but I now get the error listed above when I do not use the css with extlib.